# Convert vector of type A to type B where A is convertible to B

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust, and one of the most basic things I want to do is to take one vector of homogenous type `A` which is convertible to another type `B` (since `From<>` is implemented and thus we can use `.into()`). When I tried running the below I got the following:

```rust
struct A {
    x: String
}

struct B {
    x: String
}

impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(a: A) -> Self {
        B { x: a.x }
    }
}

impl B {
    pub fn from_many<T: Into<B> + Clone>(v: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        B { x: v.iter().map(|e| B::from(e.clone()).x).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ") }
    }
}

fn main() {
    ...
}
```

I got:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `B: From<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:41
   |
17 |         B { x: v.iter().map(|e| B::from(e.clone()).x).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ") }
   |                                 ------- ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<T>` is not implemented for `B`
   |                                 |
   |                                 required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
help: consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
   |
15 | impl B where B: From<T> {
   |        ++++++++++++++++
```

I originally tried it without the `clone()`, but thought that it didn't accept references:

```
...
impl B {
    pub fn from_many<T: Into<B>>(v: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        B { x: v.iter().map(|e| B::from(e).x).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ") }
    }
}
...
```

which yielded:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `B: From<&T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:41
   |
17 |         B { x: v.iter().map(|e| B::from(e).x).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ") }
   |                                 ------- ^ the trait `From<&T>` is not implemented for `B`
   |                                 |
   |                                 required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `From<A>` is implemented for `B`
```

I'm not asking for an arbitrary `T` here, I'm asking for `T` which has `Into<B> for T` defined (in this case, I believe it's defined since I defined the `From` trait). Did I do something stupid here?

Comment: Note the compiler is giving you a wrong suggestion, it would be greatly appreciated if you will fill a bug report.

Comment: I'd be happy to. Is there a standardized place to do so?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/new?assignees=&labels=A-diagnostics%2C+T-compiler&template=diagnostics.md. The `where` clause should be proposed on the function, not the `impl`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've done so here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/104089

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a very simple but easy to miss fact: if you have a `From<T> for U` implementation you automatically have a `Into<U> for T` implementation, *but the opposite is not true*. Thus, if by generics you require `T: Into<B>` (which is the right thing to do since it is more generic than `B: From<T>`), you need to use `.into()` and not `B::from()`:

```rust
impl B {
    pub fn from_many<T: Into<B> + Clone>(v: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        B { x: v.iter().map(|e| e.clone().into().x).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ") }
    }
}
```

Another, but unrelated, thing you're missing is that since you have an owned `Vec<T>` you can use `into_iter()` and then you don't need to `.clone()`:

```rust
impl B {
    pub fn from_many<T: Into<B>>(v: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        B { x: v.into_iter().map(|e| e.into().x).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" ") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! Disregard my previous comment (edited) this worked for me!